# Netezza stored procedure error with ^ found "" (at char 76) unterminated BEGIN_PROC string

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

I just started working on Netezza, I would like to create a simple stored procedure to go through a table using cursor or temp table like MS SQL, anyway, this simple task starts with something wrong and I have no idea on it, here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE My_FirstSP() RETURNS INT4 LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
ID int;

CREATE TABLE RX5201901
(
       ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),  
       CreatedOn DATETIME
);
END_PROC;
```

Error:

> ^ found "" (at char 76) unterminated BEGIN_PROC string

Thank you very much.

Comment: The answer posted by Lars G Olsen didn't worked for me, no such option when right clicking in my version of Aginity.
Anyway, I prefer that my client executes only to the nearest semi-colon, for solving your specific problem without changing modes you can press ctrl+f5 to compile the procedure as Single Batch.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance executing the create from aginity?

In that case You need to right-click on the background and change the setting to 'procedure mode'

Otherwise netezza only submits the sql between the two nearest semi-colons (;)

Comment: The comment by @Juan above does work.  However, I did choose to change the settting, and here's what worked for me in Aginity Workbench for PureData System for Analytics, version 4.8.0.2551:  (1) right-click the background, and select `Options`.  (2) Click the `Query kind` drop-down, and change it from `Ordinary SQL` to `SP/Function`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve this problem to create stored procedures
 Click Right >> Option >> 
     Query kind : SP/ Function

> > Ok
> >     2. CTRL + F5